# How can overcome with Cocos2D new version

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am starting to learn Cocos2D with new Beta version.In new version there are lots of change as i seen previous one.The resource that i got from internet or books are following previous one.Is there any suggestion how i will overcome it and learn Cocos2D quickly
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just go along with any version.. If a method is deprecated, your IDE will tell you and you ll have to google a solution. Sorry, i dont know specificz but its probably not relevant if u r just starting